# What is wrong with my view counter

Tags: php, mysql, view, counter

I am trying to make a view counter that counts every time someone views the page.

my code:

```
$old_views = $thread_view_count;
$new_views = $thread_view_count + 1;
$sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE forum_posts SET view_count='.$new_views.' WHERE id='.$thread_id.'");
```

The counter doesn't update the views of the page. I am not getting any errors, it just doesn't work.

Please help me, I am new to PHP so don't give me a hard time and destroy my self confidence

Thanks

- Sam

Comment: Did you check if `mysql_error` returns something? I am guessing it does. I don't call that no errors. if mysql_query returns a boolean `false` value, it means there was an error. You need to be checking that if you insist on using deprecated interfaces.

Comment: "UPDATE forum_posts SET view_count="."$new_views." WHERE id=".$thread_id

Comment: Find a good IDE with syntax highlighting, you can avoid these problems in the future. Try netbeans IDE.

Comment: You're not [properly escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which could lead to severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and you're using the deprecated `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications because it's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) shows how to avoid making these sorts of mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing your single and double quotes. You start with double quotes but then insert the variables using single quotes, which will be evaluated as a string in the query.

```
$sql3 = mysql_query('UPDATE forum_posts SET view_count='.(integer)$new_views.' WHERE id='. (integer)$thread_id);
```

Also notice I cast your values as integers so you know an integer is being passed into the database.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. I can't accept your answer yet though, I have to wait 10 minutes. thanks

Comment: @user3112869 Glad to help. I would also like to suggest that you look into protecting yourself from SQL injection. This query looks like it's probably OK but anytime the query can be altered via user input, you should either cast the value as a number or use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to make sure people can't delete your database. The best practice is to always protect yourself even if you think the query is too simple or sand-boxed to be attacked.

Comment: still suggest you do `view_count=view_count+1`, faster,safer no need to cast the variable

Answer (score 0):

easier

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE forum_posts SET view_count=view_count+1 WHERE id='.$thread_id.'");
```